# How to add more similar tasks and settings to Jan Berkel's Android Plugin in SBT?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, android-install-apk, sbt-android-plugin

I'm trying to extend [Jan Berkel's Android Plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin) for [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) that uses [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt).

I have similar actions and settings like already defined `android:install-device` and `android:install-emulator`.
Let them be called `android:dev-install-device` and `android:dev-install-emulator`.

I have added new keys in `AndroidKeys.scala`:

```
val devInstallDevice = TaskKey[Unit]("dev-install-device")
val devInstallEmulator = TaskKey[Unit]("dev-install-emulator")

val devStartDevice = TaskKey[Unit]("dev-start-device", "Start package on device after installation")
val devStartEmulator = TaskKey[Unit]("dev-start-emulator", "Start package on emulator after installation")
```

I have also added things in `AndroidLaunch.scala`:

```
lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    //AndroidInstall.settings ++
    AndroidFastInstall.settings ++
    inConfig(Android) (Seq (
        devStartDevice <<= startTask(false),
        devStartEmulator <<= startTask(true),
        //startDevice <<= startTask(false),
        //startEmulator <<= startTask(true),

        devStartDevice <<= devStartDevice dependsOn devInstallDevice,
        devStartEmulator <<= devStartEmulator dependsOn devInstallEmulator
        //startDevice <<= startDevice dependsOn installDevice,
        //startEmulator <<= startEmulator dependsOn installEmulator
    ))
```

The problem is, if I want my own tasks to be available, I have to comment out the original, standard ones, which I don't want to.

Is there anything I'm overlooking?

---

Update:
I've tried different order of settings.

When `AndroidFastInstall` comes before `AndroidInstall`, `AndroidInstall` is executed regardless I call `android:install-device` or `android:dev-install-device`.

```
  lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    AndroidFastInstall.settings ++
    inConfig(Android) (Seq (
      devStartDevice <<= devStartTask(false),
      devStartEmulator <<= devStartTask(true),

      devStartDevice <<= devStartDevice dependsOn devInstallDevice,
      devStartEmulator <<= devStartEmulator dependsOn devInstallEmulator
    ))++
    AndroidInstall.settings ++
    inConfig(Android) (Seq (
      startDevice <<= startTask(false),
      startEmulator <<= startTask(true),

      startDevice <<= startDevice dependsOn installDevice,
      startEmulator <<= startEmulator dependsOn installEmulator
    ))
```

---

When `AndroidInstall` comes before `AndroidFastInstall`, `AndroidFastInstall` is executed regardless I call `android:install-device` or `android:dev-install-device`.

```
  lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    AndroidInstall.settings ++
    inConfig(Android) (Seq (
      startDevice <<= startTask(false),
      startEmulator <<= startTask(true),

      startDevice <<= startDevice dependsOn installDevice,
      startEmulator <<= startEmulator dependsOn installEmulator
    )) ++
    AndroidFastInstall.settings ++
    inConfig(Android) (Seq (
      devStartDevice <<= devStartTask(false),
      devStartEmulator <<= devStartTask(true),

      devStartDevice <<= devStartDevice dependsOn devInstallDevice,
      devStartEmulator <<= devStartEmulator dependsOn devInstallEmulator
    ))
```

It appears that the last ones added always cover the visibilty of those prior to them.
Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question needs some additional information.

Here's the complete source code: https://github.com/ioreskovic/android-plugin

Apparently, you've copied the `settings` from in [`AndroidInstall`](https://github.com/ioreskovic/android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/AndroidInstall.scala#L184) to `devSettings` in [`AndroidFastInstall`](https://github.com/ioreskovic/android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/AndroidFastInstall.scala#L392). You then added the new task keys in `AndroidLaunch`.

The problem you are having is that apparently calling `dev-install-device` does exactly the same thing as `install-device`. This is not because one covers the visibility of the other (they are both visible, it's just that they do the same thing). The problem is that they both depend on the same set of other task keys, and you change those task keys twice - the last change shadows the one before.

More specifically, your problem is here:

```
lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  AndroidFastInstall.devSettings ++
  ...
  AndroidInstall.settings ++
  ...
```

Take a look what's inside of these `settings` and `devSettings` sequences:

`AndroidFastInstall`:

```
lazy val devSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Android) (devInstallerTasks ++ Seq (
  uninstallEmulator <<= devUninstallTask(emulator = true),
  uninstallDevice <<= devUninstallTask(emulator = false),
  ...
  >>>   proguard <<= proguardTask   <<<
```

`AndroidInstall`:

```
lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Android) (installerTasks ++ Seq (
  uninstallEmulator <<= uninstallTask(emulator = true),
  uninstallDevice <<= uninstallTask(emulator = false),
  ...
  >>>   proguard <<= proguardTask   <<<
```

Here you're redefining a task key called `proguard` which both `dev-install-device` and `install-device` depend on. The first `proguardTask` method is in `AndroidFastInstall`, the second is in `AndroidInstall` and they do different things. Since you call the second one last, it redefines what the `proguard` task means.

(I'm drawing attention to the `proguard` task key which both `dev-install-device` and `install-device` transitively depend on, but there are other examples of such task keys in `settings` and `devSettings`.)

To understand this better, you have to understand what settings and tasks really are and how they work:

- https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Basic-Def
- https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-More-About-Settings
- https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Custom-Settings

See "Defining a key" for examples of how to declare a task key.

See "Implementing a task" and "Computing a value based on other keys' values: <<=" for examples of how to implement a task.

This gist of it is - a task key is first declared and implemented later via `:=` and `<<=`. The `<<=` may be called multiple times - each call to `<<=` reimplements the task key.

To make your problems go away, create separate `proguard` keys for `dev` and regular versions of your tasks. And do the same thing for the conflicting tasks other than `proguard`.